# trying to prevent overflow of images

Tags: html, css, overflow

The photo frame contains images that are displayed in 3x4 columns.
The images spill over the photo frame and I can't seem to prevent them.
I've used 'overflow' on the photo frame but I keep getting the same results.

How do I prevent the photos from overflowing the photo frame?

**style.css**

```
.screenFrame {
    width: 350px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: #FDF6C2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .photoFrame {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .bookPhoto {
      width: 100px;
      height: 113px;
      margin: 0 5px;
    }
```

**photos.html**

```
<div class="screenFrame">
   <div id="photoFrame" class="photoFrame">
       <a class="bookInfo" href="#"><img class="bookPhoto" src="mySrc" alt="" /></a>
       etc
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the image not inside the photo frame element?

Comment: Your image tag should be `<img class="bookPhoto" src="mySrc" alt="" />` not `<img class="bookPhoto" src="mySrc"></img>`

Comment: Syntax mistake.  Problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, one, you're only setting overflow-y on the photoframe div, so it will automatically extend in the x direction.  You need to handle the x direction too.

Also, setting the height and width of the img element will scale/compress/distort your images if they aren't the same size as the style specifies.  If that's not what you want, try max-height and max-width instead.

Try these styles and see if the results are better:

```
.photoFrame {
   overflow:hidden;
   height:  113px;
   width:   120px; 
}
.bookPhoto {
   max-height: 113px;
   max-width: 110px;
   margin: 0 5px;
}
```

(the photoframe width is 120 instead of 110 to account for the 5px margin on each side)
if you want scrollbars for images that are bigger than the frame size, use overflow: scroll.  If you don't want the images to scale, instead of setting width and height for .bookPhoto, use a clip rect:

```
.bookPhoto {
   clip( 0px, 113px, 110px, 0px);
   margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: sure thing, good luck.  If you want scrolling in just one direction (say, vertically) you can do overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your markup is correct.

You set the `overflow-y` on `.photoFrame`, yet the image tag in your code it sitting outside of the `.photoframe` div.

Try changing it to this:

```
<div class="screenFrame">
   <div id="photoFrame" class="photoFrame">
        <a class="bookInfo" href="#"><img class="bookPhoto" src="mySrc" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I also closed your `<img>` tag properly.  You don't use `</img>` to close an image tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I made a syntax mistake.  I fixed it above but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can tell your never go over because you have not defined boundries for `.photoframe`. It should have an specific width and height, i'm guessing 100% for both. And also you didn't specify nothing for `#photoframe` that may also have some styles.